# trying to create function to double a number, getting

Tags: javascript

Im trying to create a function(double) that doubles any number returned. I keep getting unexpected token error. I've read and re-read eloquentjavascript on functions and cannot figure out what Im missing. Any help is appreciated

```
 var double = function(num);{
        return num * 2;
        };
        console.log(double(5));
```

Comment: Try removing semicolon `;` between parameters and statement `);{`

Comment: Between `function(num)` and the braces that follow it isn't a valid location for a semicolon. (After the closing brace of the block is fine.)

Comment: `double` is a `reserved word`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords

Comment: Depending on what enviroment you're targeting, you could also use an arrow function (which is new in ES6 or ES2015)

`var doubler = num => num * 2;`

Comment: @vp_arth : it works in chrome developer console so either document is wrong or chrome developer console doesn't implement it properly

Comment: @sumeetkumar, it works yet. while you don't want to use some utils with strict standarts supporting(like yui compressor etc.) and while ECMAScriptX don't use it.

Comment: completely agree with it. its always advisable for not to use any reserved keyword and even avoid possible duplicates as per me to create less unnecessary bugs and debug sessions in all production code. i have just taken his code and corrected it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is corrected code you have extra `;`

```
var double = function(num){
       return num * 2;
};
console.log(double(5));
```